# change interop dll version created in vb6 when using in .net

Tags: vb.net, vb6, interop, versioning

I'm facing problem while reference vb6 dll in .net project. When ever i refer a vb6 dll in .net project the interop dll is created with same version(1.2.0.0). Its creating problem for me as the setup used to deploy the application at client side does not replace the dll if the version is same as before. I want to change the version of the interop dll (created using vb6 dll). I read it cam done using tlbIMP but how to create tlb file for vb6 dll. Or is there is any other way to achieve this.

Thanks
Saurabh

Comment: You want to change the version of the VB6 DLL *without recompiling it in VB6*? If you haven't made modifications to the VB6 DLL, why should you have cause to increment the version number?

Comment: there are changes in vb6 dll, its version is updating after recomipling but the version of interop dll created while refering this dll in .net is not updating. Due to which setup is not replacing that file

Answer (score 4):

Here's a small batch file we use to create our interop dll so it's strongly named:

```
sn.exe -i MichiganLTAP.pfx MagicContainerName

tlbimp.exe ourVb6.dll /out:Our.Strongnamed.Interop.dll /asmversion:7.1.0.0 /keycontainer:MagicContainerName /machine:X86 /namespace:Our.Strongnamed /verbose /sysarray

sn.exe -d MagicContainerName
```

The important switch from your perspective is: `/asmversion:7.1.0.0`

You should be able to set that to whatever you want.  Check out the [MSDN Library page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tt0cf3sx%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) for more info on the switches available.

Comment: Yep, i'm pretty sure to be able to specify the version, you have to manually create the interop, not let VS do it for you.

Answer (score 4):

It makes *very* little sense to make the version number of the interop library different from the version number of the type library that was created by VB6.  There is a one-to-one mapping between what's in the interop library vs the code you wrote in VB6.  The interop library simply contains IL declarations for the VB6 COM interfaces, there is no actual code.  The CLR uses it to quickly generate the RCW for the interface.

Change the type library version number in VB6 with Project + Properties, Make tab, Version number.  Major and minor is what counts.  Do this only when you make a change in the publicly visible VB6 classes.  Doing so is required btw, it avoids DLL Hell.

Comment: I changed the version number in VB6 dll but the interop dll is always having version number which is different from actual version of vb6 dll. In my case the version of vb6 dll is 5.1.0.17 but interop dll version is 1.2.0.0. Changing the actual dll version doesnot effect interop dll version

Comment: Do you have the binary compatibility option turned on in VB6?